# How to move files with name containing multiple special char like 'é' 'ä' 'space'?

Tags: xargs, locale, mv, special-characters

I am trying to move my files from current dir to another dir. The issue I am having is that multiple files have a name with special characters like `space, ü, &, (, ...`. How can I move all my files using a command like: `ls | grep mp4 | xargs -i mv {} mp4`, where `{}` is supposed to be the name of the current file and mp4 the destination put all my file. I have tried the command but it shows errors. Can you please help ?

Comment: Can you show us the errors, telepathy mode is currently off line.

Comment: @richard This is the error `xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`

Comment: @dmx, the man page for GNU xargs states that _"xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines"_ so quotes are indeed special. Try e.g. `echo "'foo bar' doo\ goo" | xargs -n1 echo`.

Comment: @dmx, see the xargs-specific part [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/170373)

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly the situation [you don't want to use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in. Or `xargs` with default settings, it will split the input on spaces, and handles quotes and backslashes specially. You'd need to use `-0` to separate input on null bytes, or `-d'\n'` to separate on newlines (GNU xargs) to turn that behaviour off.

As all the files are in the same directory, you can just use the shell:

```
mv *mp4* mp4/
```

Or `mv *.mp4 mp4/` if you only meant files files that have `mp4` as an extension. The first one would warn about moving `mp4` itself to `mp4`.)

---

If the files were not in the same directory, you'd need to either use the double-star (`zsh` - enabled by default or `ksh` with `set -o globstar` or `bash` with `shopt -s globstar`):

```
mv **/*mp4* mp4/
```

or `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*mp*" -exec mv {} mp4/ \;
```

Answer (score 4):

The command:

```
ls | grep mp4 | xargs -i mv {} mp4
```

can in most cases be replaced by the simpler and more robust:

```
mv *mp4* mp4
```

You can ignore the warning about the directory mp4 not being movable inside itself.

Note that this script, like yours, is moving all files having "`mp4`" appearing anywhere in their name (e.g.: `mp4list.txt`, `lamp4.jpg`). Should you actually want to only move files with the extension "`.mp4`", you can use:

```
mv *.mp4 mp4
```

That would prevent the situation leading to the error message about the directory `mp4` itself to occur.

Should the number of mp4 files is huge and prevent the former command to work, you might use GNU `find` to achieve the same:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*mp4*" -exec mv -t mp4 {} +
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp4" -exec mv -t mp4 {} +
```